# cannot find -lboost_thread-mt

Tags: compiling

I'm getting 2 errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_thread-mt
```

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options-mt

what is the simplest way for me to install -lboost_thread-mt so that i can finish my install of PsMoveInput
please note that i need the -lboost_thread-mt and ive tried installing "all boost" which didn't work
Ive installed all the others and even read somewhere that the -lboost_thread-mt isnt available and if thats the case is there a archive i can get it from?

Thank you and sorry for my lack of technical terms.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu, and what version of libboost do you have? Have you tried installing the `libboost-thread-dev` package specifically?

Comment: @steeldriver Im trying to do it on 3 different systems. Ubuntu 14.04, Lbuntu and linux mint but i get the same errors and yes i just tried running code sudo apt-get install libboost-thread-dev . and i get this;

code Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced the same problem on installing Field3D. It seems that the file name is `libboost_thread.so` instead of `libboost_thread-mt.so`. So it is a bug and should be handled by changing the term in the source file.

For field 3D, change `buildSupport.py`. Search for the `-mt` and remove. Then Scons runs through.

Also see [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889614/missing-lboost-thread-mt-in-mongodb-cpp-driver-ubuntu-server-x64).